# Search in vertical split in vim

Tags: linux, unix, vim

I have two different files open using vertical split in Vim (say abc.txt and xyz.txt). I want to search and highlight different things in them (say search hello in abc.txt and world in xyz.txt).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to *highlight* the matches, then it seems to be a good use case for `:help :match`. Assuming the current window is the one displaying `abc.txt`:

```
:match Search /hello/
<C-w>w
:match Search /world/
```

[image: :match]